# Typescript doesn't catch prop of the wrong type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component from my Gatsby app that renders another one like so:

```js
import Header from './components/Header.tsx';
<Header siteTitle={"My site title"} />
```

And I want to check that `siteTitle` comes in as a string. I'm doing this in TS:

```
type Props = {
    siteTitle: string;
}

export const Header = ({ siteTitle }: Props) => (
  <h1>
    { siteTitle }
  </h1>
);
```

However, trying to render `<Header siteTitle={1} />` is not caught by `tsc`, which rather defeats the purpose.

It's [working as expected in this Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUIzAJ5hZwAKxY6AvHADejOHErIAJhAB2AGxZxUwGFgAqy2VgBcimFGDSA5vQYBfRoywAPSLDi4ZqeAAkcErFDgCAFIMXK1DQ5THW4IXgBKLwA+OG8ROAAeAAsARmiE0T8lFXUYTThzBlFEgHo0jIYIk0ZE10kPf1ygvkFU0zhS6KA), so I assume it could be a problem with my config.

I've checked by `tsconfig.json` a few times and can't find anything suspicious there. There it is however:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "ESNext",
     "jsx": "react",
     "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "scripts"]
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please share your tsconfig.json

Comment: @captain-yossarian I've edited my original post to include it :)

Comment: Try to change modulreResolution to AMD or UMD, but not to node

Comment: @captain-yossarian unfortunately that's not it. Changing `moduleResolution` only messes with Gatsby's imports, and does not help with this `props` problem :(

Comment: you are not getting lint error? or you are not getting build error?

Comment: @arminyahya `npx tsc` does not come up with any errors about the above, which I believe it should :(

Comment: did you try with - Header: React.FC<Props>

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue without invloving react, but only typescript? that is, create a file `header.ts` with `type Props = { siteTitle: string; }; export const Header = ({ siteTitle }: Props) => ({ siteTitle });`, and another file `useHeader.ts` with `import {Header} from './header'; Header({siteTitle:1});`. In my environment, an error is correctly displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the leads from @DevLoverUmar and @OfirD, I've found a solution to my problem. I'm posting it here in case someone finds themselves as puzzled as I am and out of options.

In my original post, I did not mention that it was `Container.js` that rendered `<Header />`, the `export` of `Header.tsx`.

Once renamed to `Container.tsx`, the compiler picks up the prop types without a hitch. All the solutions above were valid – the issue was somewhere else.

Thank you both for suggesting I set up a fresh TypeScript project!

Comment: Ok Thank U but I don't know, why someone voted my question as negative.

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way.

```
type Props = {
    siteTitle: string;
}

const Header: React.FC<Props> = ({ siteTitle }) => (
  <h1>
    { siteTitle }
  </h1>
);

export default Header;
```

Comment: Thank you Todd. I've tried just as you advised but `tsc` is still silent regarding this prop of the wrong type :(

Comment: Darn, okay, something must be wrong with your config. This is the way you are supposed to do it.